# Next JS : Failed to collect page data for when build on VPS

Tags: next.js

I have Next JS Application already hosted in VPS and data fetching using **GetStaticProps** and **GetStaticPaths**, then this application will consume REST Api from my subdomain with same VPS.

1. Next JS Application : http://zeffry.my.id
2. Rest API http://admin.zeffry.my.id/api

When i running `npm run build` on VPS, I get an error which indicates it is related to getStaticPaths.

```
zeffry@zeffryportofolio:/var/www/zeffry-reynando$ npm run build

> zeffry-reynando@0.1.0 build
> next build

info  - Loaded env from /var/www/zeffry-reynando/.env
info  - SWC minify release candidate enabled. https://nextjs.link/swcmin
info  - Linting and checking validity of types
info  - Creating an optimized production build
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data ..[AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400] {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.27.2'
    },
    method: 'get',
    url: "'http://admin.zeffry.my.id/api';/portfolio",
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: 0,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    _closed: false,
    socket: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'localhost',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: null,
      _server: null,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 13,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 60,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    _header: 'GET %27http://admin.zeffry.my.id/api%27;/portfolio HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/0.27.2\r\n' +
      'Host: localhost\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 80,
      protocol: 'http:',
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
      sockets: [Object: null prototype],
      freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'GET',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    path: '%27http://admin.zeffry.my.id/api%27;/portfolio',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [Socket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      rawTrailers: [],
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 400,
      statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
      client: [Socket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: '%27http://admin.zeffry.my.id/api%27;/portfolio',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 10,
      [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
      [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'localhost',
    protocol: 'http:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 0,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: '%27http://admin.zeffry.my.id/api%27;/portfolio',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    },
    [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
  },
  response: {
    status: 400,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    headers: {
      server: 'nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)',
      date: 'Fri, 02 Sep 2022 11:48:55 GMT',
      'content-type': 'text/html',
      'content-length': '166',
      connection: 'close'
    },
    config: {
      transitional: [Object],
      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      env: [Object],
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [Object],
      method: 'get',
      url: "'http://admin.zeffry.my.id/api';/portfolio",
      data: undefined
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: 'GET %27http://admin.zeffry.my.id/api%27;/portfolio HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.27.2\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '%27http://admin.zeffry.my.id/api%27;/portfolio',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'localhost',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    data: '<html>\r\n' +
      '<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>\r\n' +
      '<body>\r\n' +
      '<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>\r\n' +
      '<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)</center>\r\n' +
      '</body>\r\n' +
      '</html>\r\n'
  }
}

> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /portfolio/[slug]
    at /var/www/zeffry-reynando/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:743:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  type: 'Error'
}
```

This line indicate the rror :

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  try {
    const { slug } = context.params as IParams;
    const url =
      process.env["NODE_ENV"] == "development"
        ? process.env["BASE_API_LOCALHOST_URL"]
        : process.env["BASE_API_URL"];

    const portfolio = await axios.get(`${url}/portfolio/${slug}`);
    if (!portfolio.data.data) throw "Data tidak ditemukan";

    const data: PortfolioDetailInterface = portfolio.data.data;
    const props = {
      portfolio: data,
    };

    return {
      props: props,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }
};

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async (context) => {
  const url =
    process.env["NODE_ENV"] == "development"
      ? process.env["BASE_API_LOCALHOST_URL"]
      : process.env["BASE_API_URL"];

  const portfolio = await axios.get(`${url}/portfolio`);
  const arrPortfolio: PortfolioInterface[] = portfolio.data.data;
  const slug = arrPortfolio.map(function (val) {
    return {
      params: {
        slug: val.title_slug,
      },
    };
  });

  return {
    paths: slug,
    fallback: "blocking",
  };
};

export default PortfolioDetailPage;
```

I can confirm that when testing on my local machine, the application runs smoothly without any problems.

If you access this endpoint `http://admin.zeffry.my.id/api/portfolio/amerta`, response is

```
// 20220902190903
// http://admin.zeffry.my.id/api/portfolio/amerta

{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "type_application_id": 11,
    "main_technology_id": 15,
    "title": "Amerta",
    "title_slug": "amerta",
    "short_description": "amerta",
    "full_description": "<p>amerta</p>",
    "banner_image": "http://admin.zeffry.my.id/storage/images/portfolio/banner/6311b9c0e52cc1662106048.png",
    "github_url": null,
    "web_url": null,
    "google_playstore_url": null,
    "app_store_url": null,
    "created_at": "2022-09-02T08:07:30.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T08:07:30.000000Z",
    "created_by": null,
    "updated_by": null,
    "previewImages": [
      {
        "id": "c9a51e0b-4357-44a5-9b92-07f404050561",
        "portfolio_id": 1,
        "image": "http://admin.zeffry.my.id/storage/images/portfolio/preview/6311b9c2c9b281662106050.png"
      }
    ],
    "main_technology": {
      "id": 15,
      "name": "Flutter"
    },
    "type": {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "Mobile Apps"
    },
    "other_technology": [
      {
        "id": "faaf2db5-1c0c-4c05-8fa9-3da43fb4e2ce",
        "portfolio_id": 1,
        "technology_id": 15,
        "technology": {
          "id": 15,
          "name": "Flutter"
        }
      }
    ],
    "preview_images": [
      {
        "id": "c9a51e0b-4357-44a5-9b92-07f404050561",
        "portfolio_id": 1,
        "image": "http://admin.zeffry.my.id/storage/images/portfolio/preview/6311b9c2c9b281662106050.png"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Are there any settings for deploying missing?